# Linux NFS - set default user for new files on nfs share

Tags: linux, nfs, file-permissions

I use CentOs as nfs server nad 2 Centos machines as clients. I have some problems with permisions/ownership for new files/directories created from clients on nfs share.

My exports file:

```
/media/nfsshare *(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
```

And my idmap.conf:

```
[Mapping]
Nobody-User = nobody
Nobody-Group = nobody
```

Finally, fstab on clients:

```
172.18.2.132:/media/nfsshare /shared-disk nfs rw,addr=<ip> 0 0
```

I set /shared-disk permissions to 777 and all clients can create/delete files on mounted share. But:

- I don't want 777 permissions. I rather need 660
- Every file created by clients has owner: '-2 - user #-2' and group
  '-2'. I want to ownership for user who created file - system users
  for each client has the same ids, groups and group ids.

Any tips?

Comment: I think this is a CentOS 5 installation and it has a rather odd behavior. If you have the possibility go for CentOS 6 + NFSv4.

Comment: Version: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
I can't update to newer. Behavior like this is rather unacceptable. Any help..?

Comment: Is idmap running on both server and clients?

Comment: How to check this? I have only nfs and nfslock services, there is nothing related to idmap

Comment: There is something related to idmap in system log (on server): Apr 14 13:55:03 NFSLB rpc.idmapd[7511]: nss_getpwnam: name '500' does not map into domain 'localdomain'

Comment: latest kernels in RHEL6 use numeric values over the wire instead of strings. To change the behavior you need to "echo N > /sys/module/nfs/parameters/nfs4_disable_idmapping" and clean idmap change with "nfsidmap -c"

Comment: I started idmapd (rpcidmapd) on each client and now all files created on nfs share are owned by nobody. Client user has uid 500 - should I create user with id 500 on my server? So all files created on nfs share will be owned by user with id 500 on nfs server (instead of nobody) - is this correct? How can I get behavior like this?

Comment: If you want to see the same files uid/gids on client and server, then client ans server must use the same uids and gids or the same names for users and groups. In once case you need ud based mapping, in another - principal based.

Comment: I created all users groups with the same ids on my server and all clients. Also it seems I need to set domain name (in my case localhost.localdomain) in idmapd.conf file - on server and also all clients. After this, every file created by user on client on nfs share has ownership and group as I expected. But still there is problem with permissions. Group is ok, but group has permission "Read only". I need permission "Read-write" for group. It's impossible to set mask on fstab for nfs share, so how to force mask for files created on nfs share?

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your exports file to...

```
/media/nfsshare *(rw,sec=sys,sync,no_root_squash)
```